# I don't seem to have a mod folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-pixelmon

I downloaded Minecraft Forge, searched `%Appdata%`, went to `.minecraft`, but there was no 'mods' folder.

What do I do? I really want to play the Pixelmon mod.

Comment: You should be able to just add a folder called `mods` in your `.minecraft` folder. If forge is running properly, it should load those mods. If not, then it won't affect anything. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Why the down votes? It's a simple question, but a legitimate one.

Comment: @DBS I believe it is due to the lack of information provided in this question. The Question is also not quite nicely phrased.

Answer (score 6):

Just add a folder and call it mods. That should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You won't have a mods folder by default as the mods folder is only used by a mod or mods for Minecraft, namely modloaders (such as the aforementioned Forge) or meta-mods and mods requiring a mod dependency or dependencies, not by the vanilla Minecraft itself. The vanilla game doesn't support mods placed in the mods folder, only when a modloader mod is installed that is designed to look in this folder for mods that it can then load.

Therefore, **you will need to create this folder yourself**. Older modloaders used to create this folder for you, but this is no longer the case as of quite a while ago (no citable source).